# My quad looks like two triangles

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm a beginner and I don't know what's going on.
Some faces I've made look like two triangles glued together with different angles.

Removing doubles didn't do anything, nor flipping normals.

[image]

Comment: You are dealing with **non-planar** geometry. You have a quad that is cannot be flat any more, given the position of its vertices. Basically you need more subdivisions and proper placement of the vertices for a quad.

Answer (score 1):

All faces (quads and n-gons) will be divided into triangles when they are rendered. Depending on the engine the solution for that triangulation will differ a bit. This is a normal thing. If you don't like how they are triangulated you will need to do it your self.